# ClikElement() no hace nada en Raselenium

Tags: r, rstudio, selenium

Buenas tardes comunidad,

Estoy intentando usar Rsselenium para entrar dentro de una base de datos y extraer información.

Mi problema es que una vez estoy dentro de la página y me escribe los valores de búsqueda, no es capaz de entrar y clickar el botón de "Buscar"

```
driver <- rsDriver( browser = c('firefox'))
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
url <- "https://ec.europa.eu/transparencyregister/public/consultation/search.do;TRPUBLIC-ID-prod=0Te0AzD7Ro4S2IroweOcq-w6k5SMwdWiqekU_5PQQ1CzJdtTuxdg!-1989600635?firstTabActive=false"
remote_driver$navigate(url)


address_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'regStartDate')
address_element$sendKeysToElement(list("23/06/2008"))


button_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'css', value = '.navbar-btn')
button_element$clickElement()
```

Gracias de antemano

Aritz

Comment: Bienvenido olivetti03 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que exista un problema al encontrar el elemento que quieres

Yo utilizando xpath pude hacer click en buscar.

```
button_element <- remote_driver$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="dataReport"]/div[12]/button[2]')
button_element$clickElement()
```

Espero eso solucione tu problema.
Saludos